# thinking sphinx and console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am having a problem with Thinking sphinx on webfaction -- I have no probelem when I do it locally on osx.

I search

**>> ThinkingSphinx.search 'raymond'**

and my response is this:

=> []

any ideas?

thx

sg

Comment: Dumb question, but did you index your data at the webfaction server?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already, you should run `rake ts:index`

If you would like your search to update every time you make a change, I would suggest looking into [Delta Indexes](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AwesomePrint by any chance?

I am and that is what was causing my problem.

You can see the bug report here:

https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/issues/257